# matching sites in different dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, extract

I have more than one data frame that looks like this: 
with many species in columns that i do not report here. 
d1:

```
Year   Region  Sites Depth Transect Pharia pyramidatus
2000   LP     BALLENA      5        1        0.03
2000   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2000   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
2000   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00
```

d2

```
Year   Region  Sites      Depth Transect Pharia pyramidatus
2010   LP     PLAYA        5        1        0.03
2010   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2010   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
2010   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00
```

d3

```
Year   Region  Sites      Depth Transect Pharia pyramidatus
2016   LP     BALLENA      5        1        0.03
2016   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2016   LP     SUR          5        1        0.10
2016   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00
```

what i would like to do is to extract the sames sites (`Reef`) that are only presents in **each** year and rbind the results into one data frame that should look like this:

```
Year   Region  Reef      Depth Transect Pharia pyramidatus
2000   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2000   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
2000   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00
2010   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2010   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
2010   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00
2016   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
2016   LP     NORTE        20       1        0.00
```

Thank you very much for you help

Comment: And by "site" you mean `Reef`?

Comment: Also, `NORTE` is not present in `d3`, so why are you including it in final `df`?

Comment: See solution for updated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  group_by(Reef) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Year) == 3)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   Reef [2]
   Year Region    Reef Depth Transect Pharia_pyramidatus
  <int> <fctr>  <fctr> <int>    <int>              <dbl>
1  2000     LP ISLOTES     5        1                0.2
2  2000     LP   NORTE     5        1                0.1
3  2000     LP   NORTE    20        1                0.0
4  2010     LP ISLOTES     5        1                0.2
5  2010     LP   NORTE     5        1                0.1
6  2010     LP   NORTE    20        1                0.0
7  2016     LP ISLOTES     5        1                0.2
8  2016     LP   NORTE    20        1                0.0
```

**Notes:**

`n_distinct` counts the number of distinct `Year`'s for each `Reef` (since I `group_by(Reef)`). I want `distinct_n == 3` because I want to only return rows where `Reef` has a record for each `Year`, in this case 3 years. In a more general case, where there are many more `Year`'s, you might want to first find the `Year` span of your dataframe, and `filter` based on that, like the following:

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  mutate(Year_distinct = n_distinct(Year)) %>%
  group_by(Reef) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Year) == Year_distinct) %>%
  select(-Year_distinct)
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "Year   Region  Reef      Depth Transect Pharia_pyramidatus
                 2000   LP     BALLENA      5        1        0.03
                 2000   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
                 2000   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
                 2000   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00", header = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = "Year   Region  Reef      Depth Transect Pharia_pyramidatus
                 2010   LP     PLAYA        5        1        0.03
                 2010   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
                 2010   LP     NORTE        5        1        0.10
                 2010   LP     NORTE       20        1        0.00", header = TRUE)

df3 = read.table(text = "Year   Region  Reef      Depth Transect Pharia_pyramidatus
                 2016   LP     BALLENA      5        1        0.03
                 2016   LP     ISLOTES      5        1        0.20
                 2016   LP     SUR          5        1        0.10
                 2016   LP     NORTE         20        1        0.00", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it solved the problem, i have one question, how does the n_distinct(Year) == 3 works? is it 3 because of the three dataframes?

Comment: @FabioFavoretto Added explanation in my answer. I've also added a more general version in case you don't want to hardcode the number of `Year`'s in the dataframe.

Comment: you are awesome! thanks for the quick and helpful reply!

Comment: I noted that in the general case, in the output an additional column is added with "Year_distinct" it is not a problem just it should be a warning if someone would like to use this function and do not spot the new column added ;)

Comment: @FabioFavoretto If you don't want the `Year_distinct` column in the final dataset, you can just add `%>% select(-Year_distinct)` :)